# mysql - export table to csv file

Tags: mysql, csv

I've created a PHP application that books in jobs. When an employee clicks the 
**EXPORT CSV** button, I want a CSV file to download with all the SQL table information. How can I go about doing this.

I've seen some posts saying to run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM SalesOrders; OUTPUT TO 'c:\\test\\jobs.csv'
```

Comment: What do you mean by table information?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE ''c:\\test\\jobs.csv''
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM SalesOrders;
```